# Springer svjour3 transition

Tags: lyx, installing, sv-classes

Have a LaTeX2e file that compiles. Need to modify it for a Springer publication. Macros have been downloaded and installed in MiKTeX.
After inserting

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
```

2 problems appear.

```
\ institute is an undefined control sequence.
Cannot import this .tex file into Lyx:
tex2lyx -fixedenc -utf8 –f





 \documentclass[english]{article}
    \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=24pt,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[unicode=true,
     bookmarks=false,
     breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=section,colorlinks=false]
     {hyperref}

    \makeatletter
```

In response to the responses:
The package from Springer was reinstalled in MiKTeX.
The Latex below compiles. This .tex file does not import to Lyx. An error occurred while running:

```
tex2lyx -fixedenc -utf8 -f
```

Source of components:  https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Springer
For svjour3, Springer's journal class: 
1.  Extract the contents of ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global.zip to C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\springer. Notify MiKTeX of files installed above. This is done by 
1.  opening in the Windows start menu MiKTeX 2.9→Maintenance (Admin)→Settings (Admin) (if for all users)
or MiKTeX 2.9→Maintenance->Settings (if for current user). 
2.  clicking the button Refresh FNDB. 
•  Notify LyX of files installed above. This is done by 
1.  (re)starting LyX 
2.  using the menu Tools→Reconfigure

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=24pt,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=section,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{The Lxxx Convolution and Convolution Probability Function}

\author{By Jay A. Lxxx, PhD}

\maketitle
\institute{Jay A. Lxxx, PhD \
 Bter \\
 1870 Pista Drive \\
 Myville, NC 29991 \\
 Tel.: (899) 698-0033\\
 \email{lxxx@halo.com} %  \\
 %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
 } 

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

 % The correct dates will be entered by the editor

\begin{abstract}
This article has two parts and an addendum. In the first part, two
indicators along with an associated probability function are introduced
to enhance the arsenal of traders' tools. The Hull Moving Average
as described by its creator, Alan Hull, is the fastest of all moving
averages. Its construction is build from weighted moving averages.
The new indicators, although not moving averages, behave similarly,
and are not only faster than the Hull, but forecast market behavior
a few bars. The probability function sharply identifies turns in the
market.
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Hull Moving Average, Linear Regression, Probability, Extrapolation,
Stock Options} \PACS{G17 \and C51 \and C52, C53}

\section{Definition of the Lxxx Convolution Tools}

\subsection{Linear Regression and the Hull Moving Average}

\paragraph{The Hull Moving Average {[}HMA{]} was introduced in 2005. According
to Hull, `The Hull Moving Average solves the age old dilemma of making
a moving average more responsive to current price activity whilst
maintaining curve smoothness. In fact the HMA almost eliminates lag
altogether and manages to improve smoothing at the same time.' (\protect\protect\protect\protect\href{http://alanhull.com/hull-moving-average/}{How to reduce lag in a moving average})}

\paragraph{Since its introduction the Hull has found popularity with stock,
stock option and currency traders. Effectively, the Hull Moving Average
is faster than all other moving averages. In addition, it is smoother
than them. Because of this many accept that a bull trend is determined}

\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\protect\includegraphics[clip]{\string"Fig 1\string".jpg} 
\par\end{centering}
\protect\caption{Details 31 bars of daily SPY data, its moving linear regression, Hull
interpolation and Hull Moving Average.}
\end{figure}


\paragraph{when only 2 consecutive points indicate a rising market; bear when
falling. Its speed is the square root of its length. The speed of
a simple moving average is a much larger half its length. }

\paragraph{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have two `\documentclass` lines in your code. We need a link for the macros you installed if they are not part of standard distributions. We need a complete small example we can use to reproduce the problem. This should include packages only if they are essential to reproduce the error. You will also need a line including `\institute`, I assume, unless the lack of this is causing the error? You should certainly not be loading `geometry`, `mathptmx`, `setspace`, `wrapfig`, `float`, `fix-cm` and maybe not `hyperref` unless the instructions say to do so as these will override the class style.

Comment: Please don't expect LyX to magically work with every publisher template available out there. The LyX guys spend a lot of time to create layout files for the users. I think they did one for springer as well, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalled Miktex and Springer macros. Macros now recognized.